# Customizing reports that can be exported to Excel

Tags: filter

Can I export the orders to a csv file? I'd like to know what our customers purchased as some of our sales are from development and others from the shop and I need to separate these totals for accounting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
In order tabs at the bottom of the order table you can found out the export button.

[image]